# Receiver doesn't work after restart

Tags: android, receiver

After i restart or turn on my device my receivers don't working.
When i don't restart or turn on my device they are working...

Manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".ActionReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String msg=intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        String note=intent.getStringExtra("note");

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, alarmDialog.class);

        startIntent.putExtra("msg",msg);
        startIntent.putExtra("note",note);
        startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(startIntent);
}
```

Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(addOne.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("msg", title.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("note", note.getText().toString());

AlarmManager alarmMgr=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent,     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

Comment: This intent, which you're receiving is custom? Do you send it yourself?

Comment: i send it by PendingIntent.getBroadcast with alarmManger

Comment: Can you provide sending code please?

Comment: Did you try to implement receivers programmaticaly?

Comment: Yes, do you know how do it?

Comment: @NikMyers i know how to do it but with pendingIntent no...can you help me?

Comment: It doesn't matter which intent you're sending and how, you just need to register receiver by code, like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073957/broadcast-receiver-not-working-in-some-cases you can see code in question

Comment: @NikMyers what about [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134203/how-to-use-registerreceiver-method) first answer